# Inspect element in Google chrome showing parent tag and not the exact tag inspected

Tags: html, google-chrome, tags, parent, web-inspector

When I inspect some element, say button in a form in chrome browser, it's showing form tag rather than button HTML tag.

For some elements it is showing exact tag but sometimes it shows parents tag.

Comment: can you put up an example somewhere or share link? Need more info

Comment: Here I have inspected the upvote and got the parent tag. http://i.imgur.com/WBTM1qh.png

Comment: Thats weird, I clicked on the number and it shows me the code and not parent : http://prntscr.com/78y1nm

Comment: Is this happening only with chrome for you?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it by setting `pointer-events: none` to parent and `pointer-events: auto` to the element.